# Angular2 how to login with spring security and make rest api call

Tags: spring-mvc, angular, spring-security

Angular2 Spring security enabled.

I am not getting much information on following issue, i appreciate any help.

Using angular2 I am trying to make `http` get call to rest api which requires login first using spring security and then access to rest api.

I am running resp app under jboss eap and angular2 web project using lite-server.

spring is configured as following to access resources

```
context.setSessionTrackingModes(singleton(COOKIE));
context.getSessionCookieConfig().setHttpOnly(true);

context.addFilter("springSecurity", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
    .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    context.addServlet("login", new HttpServlet() {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String loginPage = "login.html";
        String query = request.getQueryString();
        response.sendRedirect(query != null ? loginPage + '?' + query : loginPage);
    }
}).addMapping("/login");
```

This is my angular2 api call, i am getting

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/abc/api/menu. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

getItems():Promise<Item>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/abc/api/menu').toPromise().
    then(response => response.json() as Menu).catch(this.handleError)

}
```

Comment: Problem is that your login system redirects to a login page, and you're using session cookie, which is invalid in REST (stateless api). You should configure your spring-security to get a key from request (headers) and check authentication using this key. See http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/#ch_3_3

Comment: i appreciate your help, you can post it as ans i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
context.addServlet("login", new HttpServlet() {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String loginPage = "login.html";
        String query = request.getQueryString();
        response.sendRedirect(query != null ? loginPage + '?' + query : loginPage);
    }
})
```

You tell spring that to authenticate, you have to redirect user to the login page, and this is not possible using an API call (only one request).

Also, you have to remove the usage of session cookies, since REST is, by definition, stateless.

You have to implement a stateless authentication based on a token provided with every request. One good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/#ch_3_3) but you can still find more if you look for stateless authentication for spring rest api.

Comment: I have combined angular2 code and restful project. placed angular code configuration and code inside rest project web-apps folder. turned on typescript watcher and update code hot swap in intellij works like charm. i just wanted to do it for dev enviornment